# Mathematical calculations not showing correct results in VueJs

Tags: javascript, excel, vue.js

I want to perform a series of calculations but my last one does not give me the desired result.

So, below are my input fields:

```
<div class="affordability-input">
    <input type="text" v-model="gross_income" placeholder="Enter gross monthly income (R)">
    <input type="text" v-model="loan_term" placeholder="Payment term (years)">
    <input type="text" v-model="interest_rate" placeholder="Interest Rate (%)">
    <button @click="calculate" class="bg-blue">Calculate</button>
</div>
```

I have to calculate monthly repayment, monthly interest and total repayment and all seems to work.
monthly repayment = mr
monthly interest rate = mir
total repayment = tr

```
this.n = parseFloat(this.loan_term) * 12;
this.mr = parseFloat(this.gross_income) * 0.3;
this.mir = parseFloat(this.interest_rate) / 12;
this.tr = parseFloat(this.n) * parseFloat(this.mr);
```

Then I have to calculate how much a person afford and the formula looks like the one in the image below:

[image]

With respect to the formula, P is the same as this.mr, r is the this.mir and n is the this.n.

I wrote the formula like this:

```
this.aff = this.mr * ((1 - Math.pow(( 1 + parseFloat(this.mir)), - parseFloat(this.n))) / parseFloat(this.mir));
```

and my entire method looks like this:

```
calculate(){
        this.n = parseFloat(this.loan_term) * 12;

        this.mr = parseFloat(this.gross_income) * 0.3;

        this.mir = parseFloat(this.interest_rate) / 12;

        this.tr = parseFloat(this.n) * parseFloat(this.mr);

        this.aff = this.mr * ((1 - Math.pow(( 1 + parseFloat(this.mir)), - parseFloat(this.n))) / parseFloat(this.mir));

        this.show = true;               
        this.take = false;              

}
```

When I put the formula in my calculator I get the same result that the excel sheet shows me, but I get a different result on the web page.

Is there anything I am doing wrong with my affordability calculator? The formula on the image above. How can I write that formula in Javascript/vuejs

Edited:

I created a snippet

Gross income = 60000
Loan term = 20
interest rate = 10

All the answers seem correct, except the affordability.

I created a snippet for it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Wosley_Alarico/dk5a480m/7/)

Comment: Why are you re-`parseFloat`ing `this.mir` and `this.n` in  your `this.aff` expression?

Comment: Use the [`.number` modifier](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#number) so you don't have to `parseFloat` everything.

Comment: I just remove to this: this.aff = this.mr * ((1 - Math.pow(( 1 + this.mir), -this.n)) / this.mir); but still receive the wrong result

Comment: What are some of the values you're putting in, what are you expecting to get, and what are you actually getting?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but I would strongly suggest using readable names for your variables `n`, `mr`, `mir`, `tr` and `aff`. You do not nearly save enough time to justify the time you will spend figuring out what these variables mean later.

Comment: I just created a snippet and edited my question

Comment: @RoyJ the result for the affordability should be 1 865 243.14

Comment: @Sumurai8 I edited my snippet so you will be able to see the variables in an easy way to understand

Comment: n is going to make your power expression very small. You're going to be raising something to the power of -240, which may be too small to represent.

Comment: @RoyJIf I do this calculation in my scientific calculator and get the desired result.
Am raising to the negative number in the wrong way?

Comment: Surely your monthly interest rate is wrong, isn't it? A monthly interest rate compounds. I believe dividing by 12 leaves you with too high of an interest rate at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Your interest rate needs to be divided by 100 to account for the fact that it's a percent value. 10% means 0.1.

Comment: Is there a way I can use decimal separator for such huge numbers?

Comment: See [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)